# Adding australian table rates in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.8

I am looking to add table rates for shipping within Australia in Magento 1.8.

The store is based in Australia and only ships to Australia. When I attempt to import the following CSV, Magento spits out an error stating that the "File has not been imported" and the codes are "invalid".

```
"Country","Region/State","Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
"AU","*","*","250","0"
"AUS","VIC","*","0","11"
"AUS","NSW","*","0","12"
"AUS","QLD","*","0","13"
"AUS","ACT","*","0","14"
"AUS","NT","*","0","15"
"AUS","WA","*","0","16"
"AUS","SA","*","0","17"
"AUS","TAS","*","0","18"
```

I know of and have used the [fontis extension](http://www.fontis.com.au/magento/extensions/australia) in the past but don't like how bloated it is with the extra features i have no use for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some poking around in the tables i found the following solution.

Firstly you need to add the states you require to the `directory_country_region` table. Make sure this is auto incrementing and use `AU` for the `country_id`.

I ran the following query:

```
INSERT
    INTO `your-database-name`.`directory_country_region` 
        (`region_id`, `country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) 
    VALUES 
        (NULL, 'AU', 'VIC', 'Victoria'), 
        (NULL, 'AU', 'NSW', 'New South Wales'),
        (NULL, 'AU', 'QLD', 'Queensland'),
        (NULL, 'AU', 'ACT', 'Australian Captial Territory'),
        (NULL, 'AU', 'NT', 'Northern Territory'),
        (NULL, 'AU', 'WA', 'Western Australia'),
        (NULL, 'AU', 'SA', 'South Australia'),
        (NULL, 'AU', 'TAS', 'Tasmania');
```

After these rows have been inserted take a note of their respective `region_id` for use in the `directory_country_region_name` table.

I ran the following query line by line. Make sure you update the `region_id` to match the id created in the last query.

```
INSERT 
    INTO `your-database-name`.`directory_country_region_name` 
        (`locale`, `region_id`, `name`) 
    VALUES 
        ('en_AU', '485', 'Victoria'),
        ('en_AU', '486', 'South Australia'),
        ('en_AU', '487', 'Western Australia'),
        ('en_AU', '488', 'Northern Territory'),
        ('en_AU', '489', 'Queensland'),
        ('en_AU', '490', 'New South Wales'),
        ('en_AU', '491', 'Australian Capital Territory'),
        ('en_AU', '492', 'Tasmania');
```

Now create a new account using an Australian address and notice that we now get a drop down with these values populated! Huzzah!

I can now import my CSV inside table rates in Magento without issue.

```
"Country","Region/State","Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
"AUS","*","*","250","0"
"AUS","VIC","*","0","11"
"AUS","NSW","*","0","12"
"AUS","QLD","*","0","13"
"AUS","ACT","*","0","14"
"AUS","NT","*","0","15"
"AUS","WA","*","0","16"
"AUS","SA","*","0","17"
"AUS","TAS","*","0","18"
```

I would love to make this query automatically use the `region_id` from the `directory_country_region_name` table, if anyone has any hints on how this can be improved I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is this really what is involved? Seems pretty crazy.

Comment: Also, how come your first line has 'AU' not 'AUS'?

Comment: Yep :( this is the minimal steps required to add Australian regions. Good pick up on the stray 'AU' on the first line - a typo on my part I will amend the error now.

Comment: Not sure adding to `directory_country_region_name` is required unless you use a locale that needs a translation of a region's `default_name`. I used only two-character country codes in the CSV (as other examples suggest) and that worked for me.